# Material UI Rating Component not displaying correct value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to render a component loop that takes in async data. It currently works fine and renders properly, except for the first component that is rendered, where the Rating component isn't displaying its value properly (it's just displaying 0 stars).

The code is as follows

```
        <Grid 
            container 
            item 
            direction="column" 
            alignContent="center" 
            className={reviewOpen ? '' : classes.closedReviewFormCardBlock}
        >
            {reviews && reviews.map((review) => (
                <ReviewCard review={review} userId={localStorage.getItem('userId')}/>
            ))}
        </Grid>
```

reviews here is the async data that is an array of objects that contain information about a review.

```
    const ReviewCard = ({review, userId}) => {
    ...
    return (
            ...
            <Grid item>
                <Rating defaultValue={review.rating} readOnly />
            </Grid>
            ...
            )
    }
```

Surrounding the Rating I have other components that use the same review object passed in as a prop, which also render perfectly fine. Also when I console log review.rating, it contains the correct rating but i honestly have no idea why its not displaying properly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `controlled` component, but you are not using one. Set it to `value` instead of `defaultValue`.

I'll bet that's what is happening is you end up rendering the component the first time before fetching the rating, setting it's defaultValue to 0 or something like that. Then you render again, but because you're using an `uncontrolled` component with `defaultValue`, it doesn't update when the prop changes. If you just use `value` instead of `defaultValue`, I imagine everything will work out.

When you specify `defaultValue` - that means you are using what's called an `uncontrolled` component - the initial value will be set (hence `defaultValue`) but subsequent updates (even to `defaultValue`) will do nothing.

**If there's a chance that a state change somewhere will update the value, then you want a `controlled` component - use `value` instead of `defaultValue`.**

Comment: Strange, I initially had it set as a value and it didnt work. Thats why I had set it to defaultValue to see if that changed anything. But it works now! Thanks :)